# Use of "especially"

Tags: grammar

Is there anything wrong with the use of "especially" in this sentence?

> Since then, his popularity has increased in other countries, especially Russia, Korea, Thailand, Malaysia, Singapore, and Taiwan.

I don't know if to add "in" after especially up there or not. Even with that something seems wrong with the use of especially followed by a list of countries. Anything wrong or is it just me?

Comment: This should probably be migated to [ell.SE].

Comment: It is unusual to use _especially_ before such a long list, but otherwise unobjectionable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the definitions of *especially* by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/especially):

> **1** used to single out one person or thing over all others:
>   *he despised them all, especially Sylvester
>
>   a new song, written especially for Jonathan*
>
> **2** to a great extent; very much:
>   *he didn’t especially like dancing*
>
> [*as submodifier*]:
>   *sleep is especially important in growing children*

The example in the question uses the first definition correctly. Usually *especially* is applied to a single thing, and although several countries are mentioned, it's referring to those countries collectively.

*Especially* was incorrectly used for comedy effect in *[The Simpsons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZsX6t5djd0)*:

> Sideshow Bob: Madam, your children are no more than a pair of ill-bred troublemakers.
>
> Homer: Lisa too?
>
> Sideshow Bob: Especially Lisa... But *especially* Bart.

Comment: Moving this to ELL may be a nice idea.